# A Coq program which constructively proves the halting problem

Tags: coq

I'm looking for a [constructive proof](https://proofassistants.stackexchange.com/a/2600/3074) of the halting problem in Coq. The proof sketch described on this [wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Halting_problem#Proof_concept) is constructively valid. However, I am not sure how to translate this into Coq because of the 'loop_forever' term. How can I introduce in Coq a subroutine that loops forever? In order to be constructively valid, don't I need to actually introduce or construct a non-halting program - and then affirmatively prove its non-halting behavior - to then go on to affirmatively prove the contradiction at the heart of the halting problem?  IOW, in a constructive proof, to assert that a program never halts, I need a proof that explicitly demonstrates this non-termination, right? How can I demonstrate such a thing?

-- It is stated in an answer that, "Instead, you construct a Turing machine, and then prove that it loops forever, which is quite possible, even constructively." I guess my question is how to do this in Coq?

Thanks!

Comment: As for how you define Turing machines, see for example https://github.com/uds-psl/coq-library-undecidability/blob/coq-8.18/theories/TM/TM.v

Alternatively, you can also try defining them yourself, following any textbook on computability theory, which should include a sufficiently formal definition of a Turing Machine.

Comment: Are you looking to prove the classic theorem about non-existence of a halting oracle for Turing machines, or would any other form that indirectly proves the same fact also be acceptable? Is this just an exercise, or is there a deeper goal?

Answer (score 3):

Your question is omitting two crucial details:

- Which model of computation underpins our notion of undecidability?
- Which model of computation are we considering the halting problem for?

In computability theory, there is sometimes the habit of "hand-waving" this away. The Wikipedia article you linked is one such case: It apparently uses Python (which has no formal definition) as the model of computation for the Halting problem, but does not mention which model underpins the notion of undecidability. Which is OK there, since it is only a proof sketch, and the proofs often kind of work the same way in different models.

When you want to be fully formal (like when mechanizing it in Coq), these questions become important. The canonical model here is Turing machines (as model of computation for both, but definitely for the notion of undecidability).
This would mean that your question is to provide a constructive proof that "there is no Turing machine $M$ that, if given an encoding $E$ representing the Turing machine $M'$, decides if $M'$ halts (on the empty input)."

Mechanizing this in Coq is possible in principle, albeit a bit tedious, since you need to make the encodings formal, and also construct a Turing Machine computing its own encoding, and then prove it correct, etc.

But notice that this never defines a Coq term that says "loop forever." Instead, you construct a Turing machine, and then prove that it loops forever, which is quite possible, even constructively.

Remember that Coq (or rather: simplified formal models of Coq's internal logic) is strongly normalizing, which entails that no closed term reduces forever. Thus, the Halting problem for Coq is actually decidable, and trivially so: Everything terminates. This is quite important, since naively non-terminating programs make the logic unsound. Therefore:

> How can I introduce in CoQ a subroutine that loops forever?

You can't. At least not in the way you want to. Also note that "$x$ does not terminate" is not even a property you can state in the internal logic of Coq.

> How can I demonstrate [a non-terminating program to be non-terminating]?

By choosing a model of computation that allows you to actually construct non-terminating programs, like Turing machines.

Comment: See my update. I guess I'm asking how you operationalize, "Instead, you construct a Turing machine, and then prove that it loops forever, which is quite possible, even constructively." How can we do this in a fully constructive way?

Wouldn't it involve a constructively created witness that the given Turing machine does in fact loop forever?

Comment: A Turing machine state $S$ is said to "loop forever" if for any $n$, the Turing machine state after $n$ state transitions is not a final state. With this definition, it is easy to show that a Turing machine with one state that just spins in this state is divergent. The proof is fully constructive:
* Introduce $S$ (which is the one non-final state), $n$
* Do induction on $n$
  + After $0$ steps, the state is $S$, which is non-final
  + After $n+1$ steps, the state is still $S$, since it was $S$ after $n$ steps and our TM has the identity state transitions.

Comment: But how can you define that in CoQ given the fact that CoQ is not turing complete. How would you embody that Turing machine for some tape given input that is non-halting? In order to prove it truly constructively don't you need to show/embody an actual non-halting machine in CoQ?

Comment: You are confusing Coq the programming language and Coq the language to state theorems in. Those two have a deep connection, but when you just care about theorem proving, this is basically noise and can be ignored. You can define what it means to be a Turing Machine. You can write down the step relation. You can state the theorem above (about unboundedly many states), and you can prove it. None of this involves writing a non-terminating Coq function. Really, it does not involve defining any Coq function that does serious computation.